# A program to recognize words made up from any combination of given three words

Tags: java

I am trying to write a java program which takes in as input a string and checks if it is valid or not. The rules for deciding are:

1) The string is recognizable if and only if it contains the words "pi", "ka","chu" as its fragments, in any order repeated any number of times .
2) If it contains any other fragments( or subsequence), Then it is unrecognizable

For ex- "pikachu" consisits of "pi", "ka","chu"  only and so it is recognizable.
"kachupi" consists of "ka","chu","pi"  only and so it is recognizable.
"pipi" is also recognizable" as it contains "pi" two times.
"pich" is not recognizable as there is "ch" which is not one of the specified subsequences.

I am posting my java code below. But it's not working properly. Please check it and help.
Thanks in advance!

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class RecognisingWords {


    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
    {

        Scanner inp= new Scanner(System.in);
        String str;
        int len;
        System.out.println("Enter the string to be tested:");
        str=inp.nextLine();
        System.out.println(str);

        while(str !=null)
        {

        if(str.startsWith("pi"))
        {
            len=str.length();
            str= str.substring(2,len);          
        }

        else if(str.startsWith("ka"))
        {
            len=str.length();
            str= str.substring(2,len);          
        }

        if(str.startsWith("chu"))
        {
            len=str.length();
            str= str.substring(3,len);          
        }

        else
        {
            System.out.println("Unrecognisable Sequence");
            break;
        }

        }

        if(str == null)
        {
            System.out.println("Recognisable Sequence");
        }


    }

}
```

Comment: What exactly does "not working properly" mean?  What were the inputs and outputs?

Comment: I mean its not giving the correcyt output

Comment: Enter the string to be tested: pikachu recognisable sequence

Answer (score 2):

You need to make two changes:

First, change

```
if(str.startsWith("chu"))
```

to

```
else if (str.startsWith("chu"))
```

otherwise a string like "pipi" will fail the test.

Second,

```
while(str !=null)
```

will never fail, because `str` will never be `null`.  You need to test for emptiness:

```
while (str.length() > 0)
```

Comment: But still the same wrong outtput..

Comment: Also, `str.substring(2)` will work; you don't need to calculate and specify the length.

Comment: Yups... got it ... Thnx a lot